# Dynamic import style and set scss variable value

Tags: css, reactjs, if-statement, sass, styles

I have an admin template in which I would like user to provide option to switch between different theme color such as dark/light theme along with setting variable values, but I'm unable to conditionally import style files.

```
@if $light-theme {
    @import "./_metronic/_assets/sass/themes/layout/aside/light.scss";
    $primary: green;
} @else {
    @import "./_metronic/_assets/sass/themes/layout/aside/dark.scss";
    $primary: blue;
}
```

Getting error: Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins.

Answer (score 0):

Also it is a very long wished item to sass ... as the error message returns: that is not possible. (https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/279)

But what you can do is setting a theme variable and import your theme files. Every theme file has an conditional output based on the theme variable:

```
$theme: 'light-theme';
@import 'path/dark-theme';
@import 'path/light-theme';


// EVEREY THEME FILE WITH STRUCTURE:
@if( $theme == 'this-theme' ){

   /* 
      here goes your theme variables or 
      if whanted your theme code in the file 
   */

}
```

Comment: Hi @Brebber thanks for your response, but I won't be able to code as you mentioned I want to import those style files conditionally as those files also have other imports

Comment: @FarhanShaikh Unfortunately this indeed cannot be done in Sass itself. Even not in the new version Dart Sass. Maybe you have a chance using external techniques. I have read about such techniques but don't have any experience with it myself so I cannot say much about it. Here are the links: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/965#issuecomment-103384773 || https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-conditional-importer Hope it will help a little bit.